# Using base_score with XGBClassifier to provide initial priors for each target class

Tags: python, xgboost, xgbclassifier

When using XGBRegressor, it's possible to use the `base_score` setting to set the initial prediction value for all data points. Typically that value would be set to the mean of the observed value in the training set.

Is it possible to achieve a similar thing using XGBClassifier, by specifying a value for every target class, when the `objective` parameter is set to `multi:softproba`?

E.g. computing the sum of each occurrence for each target class in the training set and normalizing by percentage of total would give us:

```
class      pct_total
--------------------
blue       0.57
red        0.22
green      0.16
black      0.05
```

So that when beginning its first iteration, XGBClassifier would start with these per-class values for every data point, instead of simply starting with `1 / num_classes` for all classes.

Is it possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this using the parameter `base_margin`.  Read about it [in the docs](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/prediction.html#base-margin); the referenced demo is [here](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/examples/boost_from_prediction.html), but it uses the native API and `DMatrix`; as the docs say though, you can set `base_margin` in the `XGBClassifier.fit` method (with new enough xgboost).

The shape of `base_margin` is expected to be `(n_samples, n_classes)`; since xgboost [fits multiclass models in a one-vs-rest fashion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62350750/10495893), you're providing for each sample its base score for each of the three separate GBMs.  Note also that these values are in the log-odds space, so transform accordingly.  Also don't forget to add `base_margin` to every prediction call (now *that* would be nicer as a builtin that would be saved to the class...see again the linked question earlier in this paragraph).

Comment: Thanks for the input. Related to your first point, wouldn't we simply reuse the same values set in training (assuming we'd have saved them to some place accessible at predicting time)?

Comment: D'oh!  Yes, I was thinking about it wrongly as giving the row the base margin corresponding to its class (which you wouldn't know at prediction time), but in fact you're passing all three margins.  Will edit.